# Linear Differential Operator

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-operators

> Let $\phi({D})$ be a differential operator defined by
>   $$D^n+a_{n-1}D^{n-1}+a_{n-2}D^{n-2}+...+a_0=\sum_{j=0}^{n}a_jD^j$$
>
> with constant coefficients $a_j$ (setting $a_n=1$) and the derivative
>   operator $D=\frac{d}{dx}$. Let $f(x)$ be an arbitrarily often
>   differentiable function. Show that:
>
> 1. $\phi(D)[e^{\lambda x}f(x)]=e^{\lambda x} \phi(D+\lambda)f(x)$
> 2. $\phi(D)[x f(x)]=x \phi(D)f(x)+\phi'(D)f(x)$

It's relatively easy to show that this is true for the first couple of terms but I don' know how to show it for all $n$. Is there some elegant quick way to show that 1. and 2. are true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In both cases first verify the claim for $\phi(D)=D,$ then by induction for $\phi(D)=D^n$ (this is the most interesting step), then by linearity for a general polynomial $\phi.$

Or if you are as lazy as I am, your first step could even be the constant $\phi(D)=1.$

Answer (score 0):

For 1, suppose $D^ke^{\lambda t}f(t)=e^{\lambda t}(D+\lambda)^kf(t)$ holds for $1\leq n\leq k$. We show it holds for $n=k+1$:

\begin{align}D^{k+1}e^{\lambda t}f(t)&=DD^ke^{\lambda t}f(t) \\ &=D\left[e^{\lambda t}(D+\lambda)^k f(t)\right] \\  &= e^{\lambda t}\lambda(D+\lambda)^k f(t)+e^{\lambda t}D(D+\lambda)^kf(t)\\ &=e^{\lambda t}\left[\lambda (D+\lambda)^k+D(D+\lambda)^k\right]f(t) \\ &=e^{\lambda t}(D+\lambda)^{k+1}f(t).\end{align}